# How to prove a set of matrices form a representation of Lie algebra?

Tags: particle-physics, group-theory, group-representations, commutator, lie-algebra

When reading Paul Langacker's [The Standard Model and Beyond](http://sns.ias.edu/~pgl/SMB/), I am quite confused on equation 3.29, which says with a set of fields $\Phi _a$, where $a$ goes from 1 to $n$, are chosen to be transformed to it self by Lie algebra generators $T^i$. Therefore we make the following assumption

$$
\left[ T^i , \Phi _a \right] \equiv - L_{a b}^i \Phi _b
$$

It is then said $L^i$ can be easily proven to form a representation of Lie algebra $U_G = e^{- \mathrm{i} \beta ^i T^i}$.

Well, I think if one can prove that $L^i$ and $T^i$ satisfy the same commutation relation, this conclusion is then true. But how do we do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure if this is related but the structure constants of the Lie algebra form the components of the adjoint representation of that algebra. If you make the matrix from the structure factors, you get a valid representation of the algebra which obeys the same commutator relations. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation#Structure_constants

Comment: @WhatIAm I did tried doing that, this would work only if we know the value of the commutator $\left[ \Phi _a , \Phi _b \right]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer now! It is explained in equation 3.36 and 3.37 of the same book.

First, take the adjoint of $\left[ T^i , \Phi _a \right] = - L_{a b}^i \Phi _b$, remember $T^i$ is hermitian, assume $L^i$ is real, which would lead to $\left[ T^i , \Phi _a^{\dagger} \right] = \left( L_{a b}^i \right)^T \Phi _b^{\dagger}$.

Now for a ground state $\left| 0 \right>$, assume $\Phi _a^{\dagger} \left| 0 \right> = \left| a \right>$. Also, the ground state is invariant for now, $T^i \left| 0 \right> = 0$.

Then we would have

$$
T^i \left| a \right> = T^i \Phi _a^{\dagger} \left| 0 \right> = \Phi _a^{\dagger} T^i \left| 0 \right> + \left( L_{a b}^i \right)^T \Phi _b^{\dagger} \left| 0 \right> = 0 + \left( L_{a b}^i \right)^T \left| b \right> = \left| b \right> L_{b a}^i
$$

However, it is true that $T^i \left| a \right> = \left| b \right> \left< b \left| T^i \right| a \right>$, which tells us

$$
L_{b a}^i = \left< b \left| T^i \right| a \right>
$$

Hence $L_{b a}^i$ is a representation of $T^i$ in the particle space.